# SQL OR clause priority

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with user awards, which can be of various different types.

For example, here are the records for the qualification ID 94:

[image]

So as you can see, there are 2 users, one has records for the award type of "average", "min", "max" and "final", the other has the same but no "final" award.

What I want is to get only 1 row per user. If they have an award of type "final" I want that, otherwise I want the "average" one, I don't want "min" or "max" at all.

So as an example, here is the query with just a simple IN clause:

[image]

So based on that, what I want the result to be is for the user 34562 I want the row with the "final" award, and for the user 6256 i want the row with their "average" award, since they don't have a "final" record.

I'm sure this should be fairly simple, but i'm failing miserably this morning.

I think I should be able to select the final record, then do a UNION ALL, but I can't seem to work it out in my head. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I should point out that whilst this is MySQL for me, it needs to be compatible with other database platforms.

Thanks.

Comment: Do a GROUP BY, use case expressions to do conditional aggregation.

Comment: Could you test my query quickly to see if it works. If not, I'll delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way would be to check if an average entry exists in the where clause:

```
SELECT * FROM Table t
WHERE qualid = 94
and (type = 'average' AND
    not exists(SELECT * FROM Table t2
        WHERE t.qualid=t2.qualid AND t.userid=t2.userid AND type = 'final') 
    OR type = 'final')
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to be the simplest way. I tried this earlier, but couldn't seem to get the not exists query quite right.

Comment: By the way you have a typo, you've put "not exist" instead of "not exists", in case you wanted to change it for future viewers.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using `MySQL user defined variables` which will be more scalable.

```
SELECT 
t.*
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
    *,
    IF(@sameUser = userid, @rn := @rn + 1,
        IF(@sameUser := userid, @rn := 1,@rn := 1)
    ) AS row_number
    FROM moodle.mdl_bcgt_user_qual_awards 
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @sameUser := -1, @rn := 1) AS var
    WHERE qualid = 94
    AND type IN ('final','average')
    ORDER BY userid, 
        CASE WHEN type = 'final' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END 
) AS t
WHERE t.row_number <= 1
ORDER BY t.userid
```

---

**EDIT:**

using `NOT EXISTS` & `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM your_table 
WHERE qualid = 94
AND type = 'final'

UNION ALL 

SELECT 
 *
FROM your_table A
WHERE qualid = 94
AND type = 'average'
AND NOT EXISTS (
 SELECT 1 FROM your_table B WHERE A.qualid = B.qualid AND  B.userid = A.userid AND B.type = 'final'
)
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be incompatible with other database engines? We use MySQL here, but the software supports PostgreSQL, SQL Server, etc... as well, so some places who use it won't be on MySQL.

Comment: Then you can try the other query

Comment: yeah, maybe @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure MySQL solution, which should also be generally ANSI compliant across most RDBMS:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT qualid,
           CASE WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'final' THEN 100
                              WHEN type = 'average' THEN 10
                              ELSE 1
                         END) = 100 THEN 'final'
                WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'final' THEN 100
                              WHEN type = 'average' THEN 10
                              ELSE 1
                         END) = 10 THEN 'average'
                ELSE NULL
           END AS type
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY qualid
) t2
    ON t1.qualid = t2.qualid AND
       t1.type   = t2.type
```

This query employs a trick, which is to aggregate a sum for each `qualid` group based on whether `final`, `average`, or neither be present.  I assign a value of `100` for `final`, `10` for `average`, and `1` for neither.  This allows us to assign a `type` to each group.

Comment: Hi, no it doesn't seem to work quite right, i've accepted the other guy's answer now, so don't worry about it

Comment: @ConnWarwicker Sorry, I had a typo in there, it works now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for sql Server

```
Select * from (
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION  BY type ORDER BY type) rowNo
    FROM mdl_bcgt_user_qual_awards
    WHERE qualid = 94 
    AND type in ('final','average')
    Order By type
) as t
Where rowNo=1
```

Hear we have done Order by on type as character meet our requirement if any other text then just add case and sort on the basis of that field.